# Avoid extra markup in Sharepoint Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, custom-masterpage

I am building a Public facing web site using a Publishing Portal. Im using a lot of web parts for it.

So everything works fine functionality wise but I am seeing a lot of extra markup that is generated with a web part which does not conform to the practices of Pixel perfect design.

Below is the image.

[image]

I dont want extra divs to be generated. I just want the markup starting from "fii-twitter-feeds". How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which extra div's exactly? Is this a custom webpart? which webpart are you using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Its a web part attached from Script Editor. And I want to remove the divs starting from class name "ms-webpart-zone ms-fullwidth" till "fii-twitter-feeds".

Comment: This is something created by SharePoint OOTB functionality and there is now way you can avoid creating it. Is there any specific problem you are facing due to this div elements?

Comment: @GaneshSanap  It is creating problem for responsive design so i want those divs removed.
Could you please endorse the question so that someone gives me a workaround for it or atleast some solution to work with.

Comment: You cannot remove those div elements. However, you can use the custom CSS to customize the look and feel of those extra div elements. all you have to do is use the classes of those div elements and override the CSS as per your requirements